# Different value and display value for option rows

Tags: eureka-forms

I have a need to specify different value and display values in an option row (PushRow and MultipleSelectorRow). By display values I mean the values that are displayed in the option selection view controller (not the concatenated list of selected values displayed in the form).

I know this can be done by using a custom class that conforms to Hashable and setting the options property of the row to an array of such class instances.

```
$0.options = [
  MyStruct(value: "1", displayValue: "one"),
  MyStruct(value: "2", displayValue: "two"),
  MyStruct(value: "3", displayValue: "three")]
```

However this results in the `value` of the so configured row being of type `MyStruct` when getting the form values using `form.values` as opposed to the actual value I'm interested in being `MyStruct.value`. This creates the needless complexity of having to map the form values accordingly.

I was wondering if there is a more desirable approach to achieve this? I.e. the values of the row remain a simple data type (say `String` or `Int`) but the displayed values in the option selection view controller can be customised.